# Some error occurs Using jplist JS

Tags: javascript, jplist

I am using jplist JS to for sorting and filtering, but i am getting error in console as follows:

```
(index):331 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jplist is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):331)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Solution1**: Check out this URL - [Slick Carousel Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790173/slick-carousel-uncaught-typeerror-slick-is-not-a-function)

May be you Loaded `jquery` more than one time.

- **Solution2**: You need to check which version of `jquery` support `jplist js`.