# Slick Uncaught TypeError: e(...).slick is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, slick.js

I'm aware that there's multiple questions regarding this, notably, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790173/slick-carousel-uncaught-typeerror-slick-is-not-a-function). However, the answers within that question don't resolve the issue for me so I'm opening a new question.

I'm trying to create a slider through slick and receiving two errors:

- Uncaught TypeError: e(...).slick is not a function
- jQuery.Deferred exception: e(...).slick is not a function TypeError: e(...).slick is not a function

I have slick installed via npm (`/node_modules/slick-slider/slick/`).

**This is how I'm enqueuing the scripts:**

```
function enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slick-slider-theme-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/node_modules/slick-slider/slick/slick-theme.css' );  
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_styles');

function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('slick-slider-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/node_modules/slick-slider/slick/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');

function replace_core_jquery_version() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-core' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js", array(), '3.1.1' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-migrate' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery-migrate', "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js", array(), '3.0.0' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'replace_core_jquery_version' );
```

`JQuery` is loaded before `slick.js`. But the `e(...)` suggests to me that the slick file isn't being found?

**Slick Markup + JS:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
 $('.imageCarousel__ul').slick({
   dots: true,
   infinite: false,
   speed: 300,
   slidesToShow: 4,
   slidesToScroll: 4,
   responsive: [
     {
       breakpoint: 1024,
       settings: {
         slidesToShow: 3,
         slidesToScroll: 3,
         infinite: true,
         dots: true
       }
     },
     {
       breakpoint: 600,
       settings: {
         slidesToShow: 2,
         slidesToScroll: 2
       }
     },
     {
       breakpoint: 480,
       settings: {
         slidesToShow: 1,
         slidesToScroll: 1
       }
     }
 });

});
```

```html
<?php 
 $image = shortcode_atts(
   array(
    'image' => 'image',
   ), 
   $atts 
  );

  $image_ids = explode(',',$image['image']);

  $result = "<div class='imageCarousel'>";
  $result .= "<div class='imageCarousel__container justify-content-center'>";
  $result .= "<ul class='imageCarousel__ul d-flex flex-row'>";

  foreach( $image_ids as $image_id ){
   $result .='<li class="align-items-center">';
   $result .='<img src=';
      $attachmentImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'full' );
      $result .= $attachmentImage ? $attachmentImage['0'] : '';
      $result .='>';
      $result .='</li>';
  }

  $result .= "</ul>";
  $result .= "</div>";
  $result .= "</div>";

  return $result;
?>
```

Comment: `JQuery is loaded before slick.js` This does not appear to be the case. You call `wp_enqueue_scripts` then `replace_core_jquery_version`

Comment: hmm, true, but when viewing the source of my page, slick is below JQuery? I've moved `replace_core_jquery_version` above `enqueue_styles`, but it's still resulting in an error

Comment: how does your js file begin and ends ?! The file where you fire slick.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - it doesn't matter where in the code the **wp_enqueue_script()** is, as long as the third parameter contains the handle it should come after. In this case, the **slick-slider-js** does not have **jquery-core** (the handle of jQuery) in the array, only **jquery**. That could be a problem - if there's no script with the handle of **jquery**, then **slick-slider-js** waits and waits and waits...

Comment: @LebCit - I've added the markup + JS in the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Your are putting

```
wp_enqueue_script('slick-slider-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/node_modules/slick-slider/slick/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
```

**AFTER** the `js` file that fires slick !

You should do it like this :

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function original_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'default', get_theme_file_uri( '/css/default.css' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/css/default.css' ) ) );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'slick', get_theme_file_uri( '/css/slick.css' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/css/slick.css' ) ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-js', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/slick.min.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/slick.min.js' ) ), true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/main.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/main.js' ) ), true );


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'original_scripts' );
```

`slick.min.js` HAVE TO BE BEFORE the `js` file that fires it !

Now in `main.js` :

```
(function ($) {
    $('.your-class').slick({
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Hope this will get you on track ;)